# Hide current element and show the next one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a ASP.NET application where shows you a quiz. This quiz should be show to the user displaying question by question.

I mean, appears the first question and when he press the button next, hide the current question element and show the next one until it has no elements to show.

By the moment, I just have accomplish show all of them in MVC4. I really have not to much experience using JQuery.

```
<div id="questions-container">
    <div class="question">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     ...
    </div>  
</div>
```

Can you orient about how can I implement this feature? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default all questions to `display: none;`, show the first one when the page loads (or with another class `.question.first` that has `display: block;`, and then the next button can show the next question with:

```
$("#questions-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
```

Comment: Wow, how fast you are! I'm really struggling a little bit with JQuery, can you also recomend me some sites to have practice in it?

Comment: There really isn't a better learning place other than their [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ "jQuery API documentation"), you can do almost anything regarding DOM manipulation in jQuery, so most of the time you can search _and find_ what you are looking for in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already got an answer to this. I do something very close to this in one of my sites. This counts your divs and shows the next button until you reach the last div and then it removes the button. I rewrote it to include your code above.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
    { 
    var Called = 1;
    var TotalDiv = $(".question").length;
    $(".question").filter(":first").css("display","block"); 
    $(".reveal").click(function()
        {
        Called++;
        $("#questions-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
        if(Called == TotalDiv)
            {
            $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.question{display:none;}
</style> 
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="questions-container">
    <div class="question">
     division one
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     division two
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     division three
    </div>
    <div class="question">
     division foor
    </div>  
</div>
<input type="button" class="reveal" value="NEXT" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, it looks more complete the solution. Would you mind if you check another of my questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388082/how-to-validate-the-form-in-this-scenario

Comment: when you say validate , do you mean validate if a box was checked or validate if the **correct** box was checked

Comment: the first one, in my Question model I have a property called SelectedAnswer for the radiobuttons.. and I set the tag [Required]