# Caption: Hide current element, show next one and then loop

Tags: jquery, loops, caption

I'm creating a caption area to go alongside a slideshow, so as the slideshow images change; so too do the captions.

I have had a look into this and came across [this old post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386395/hide-current-element-and-show-the-next-one)

I wish to do the exact same thing, the layout is:

```
<div id="captions-container">
    <div class="caption first">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
     ...
    </div>
    <div class="caption last">
     ...
    </div>  
</div>
```

The accepted answer to his question was:

```
$("#questions-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
```

My current script looks like so

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    $("#caption-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
});
```

Which work perfectly, but I wish to add a new feature.  When the last caption has been reached, on the next click, go back to the first caption in a typical carousel loop fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work. Using `length` of `next()` to see if it exists, otherwise start at beginning

```
$(".next").click(function() {
    var $current=$("#captions-container .caption:visible").hide();
    var $next = $current.next().length ? $current.next() : $current.siblings('.first');
        $next.show();
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dTp6a/)**</kbd>

Comment: Apologies, I missed a key point - my current code looks like this on the click event: $(".next").click(function() {
  $("#caption-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
 });

Comment: just use this in the click handler, already assumed it was tied to an external event

Comment: just noticed you had incorrect id selector based on html shown... working demo added to answer

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Apologies for my mark up, I did mis-show my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( $("#questions-container").find(":visible").hasClass('last') ) {
    $("#questions-container .last").hide();
    $("#questions-container .first").show();
}
```

I haven't tested this, but something along these lines should give you the results you are looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies, I missed a key point - my current code looks like this on the click event: $(".next").click(function() {
  $("#caption-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
 });

Comment: @Richard Teahan$(".next").click(function () {
    if( $("#questions-container").find(":visible").hasClass('last') ) {
        $("#questions-container .last").hide();
        $("#questions-container .first").show();
    } else {
        $("#caption-container").find(":visible").hide().next().show();
    }
});       Try that and let me know what you get!

Comment: I have made a fiddle of your code, it doesn't appear to be working (unless I have done something wrong, more than likely): http://jsfiddle.net/x5fm3/

Comment: I see, I revised it a little for you. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/N3ntq/[/link]